# Can't hide com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText field

Tags: android, user-interface

I just add a com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText with password "Eye" icon to one test project, now I've a very strange problem.. I can't find a way to hide the field from the xml definition.. the field appear always even with invisibile attributes.

How can I hide this kind of field? Take a look to this image on android studio

[image]

below from emulator, android 6 :

[image]

Comment: did you try to hide outer element? `<Outer><Inner></Inner></Outer>`

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion work, I'm  a little bit confused.. I just think that i can hide a single element of TextInputLayout instead the entire block!